# Integration Tests : Facility of type '....LoggingFacility' has already been registered with the container

Tags: asp.net-core, integration-testing, aspnetboilerplate

I'm setting up an Integration Test Project for `Aspnet Core MVC`.

I'm using `AspNetBoilerplate`.

I created a project with this `WebApplicationFactory`:

```
public class CustomWebApplicationFactory : WebApplicationFactory<Program>
{
}
```

And my test classes inherit from

```
public partial class ScenarioTest : IClassFixture<CustomWebApplicationFactory>
{
```

When I run the whole test suite, I get either of those errors:

```
Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentRegistrationException : Component iloggerfactory could not be registered. There is already a component with that name. Did you want to modify the existing component instead? If not, make sure you specify a unique name.

System.ArgumentException : Facility of type 'Castle.Facilities.Logging.LoggingFacility' has already been registered with the container. Only one facility of a given type can exist in the container.

Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.HandlerException : Can't create component 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerProvider_e02ce050-f09e-48d5-b518-57e4ee2ef81b' as it has dependencies to be satisfied.
```

Then when I try to run the test suite for a second time, I get this:

[image]

Cleaning the test project and re-running it makes the errors appear again

Though, I can run a single test class (With ReSharper), and the test class runs successfully.

Help with this would be greatly appreciated, as I cannot run a continuous testing session and it's quite annoying

Comment: `WebApplicationFactory<Program>` → `WebApplicationFactory<Startup>`

Answer (score 1):

Change `WebApplicationFactory<Program>` to `WebApplicationFactory<Startup>`.

Comment: This was not the issue. I found that running many tests would continuously re-run the startup. The problem was that aspnetboilerplate re-used its IocManager.IocContainer over and over. I overrode this by specifying options.iocmanager = new iocmanager in the aspnetboilerplate ServiceCollection.AddAbp callback. This way, each time startup is run, (each test fixture), a clean iocManager will be present.

Comment: Post that as an answer.